# Store access token in OAuth2.0 application and use it repeatedly until it expires?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm  developing an OAuth2.0 "CLIENT" application which call some APIs(secured by oauth2.0).
I'm using OAuth2.0RestTemplate which contains CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, username and password. The code for calling OAuth2.0 secured APIs looks like this:

```
@Bean
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        List<String> Scopes = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        Scopes.add("read");
        Scopes.add("write");
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        resource.setId("*****");
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
        resource.setClientId("*****");
        resource.setClientSecret("*****");
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setScope(Scopes);
        resource.setUsername("*****");
        resource.setPassword("*****");
        return resource;
    }



@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;


Map<String, String> allCredentials = new HashMap<>();
allCredentials.put("username", "***");
allCredentials.put("password", "***");
        restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest().setAll(allCredentials);
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObject>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {        };
ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://***.*****.com/api/*****/*****",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                responseType);
AllCities all = new AllCities();
all.setAllCities(response.getBody());
```

As you can see everytime I want to call a service the code get a new ACCESS TOKEN which is wildly wrong!!! My question is how can I automatically receive and store the issued token in my application an use it until it expires and then automatically get a new one?
On the other hand my token only contains access token and doesn't contain refresh token(I don't know why!!! this is so weird!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can design like google client library.
First step you need to create the datastore for store the token 
 in your directory like C:/User/soyphea/.token/datastore.

Before you load your function retrieve access_token_store. Your access token should have expired_in.

```
 if(access_token_store from your datastore !=null && !expired){
         access_token = access_token_store.
        } else {
          access_token = Your RestTemplate function for retrieve access_token.
 }
```

finally you can retrieve access_token.

In spring security oauth2 if you want to support refresh_token you need to set,

```
 @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients.inMemory()
                        .withClient("resource-serv")
                        .scopes("read")
                        .resourceIds("my-resource")
                        .secret("secret123")
                        .and()
                        .withClient("app")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
                        .scopes("read")
                        .resourceIds("my-resource")
                        .secret("appclientsecret");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have define that your app is a Oaut2App for this in Spring boot you can use the annotation @EnableOAuth2Client in your code and configure the client application metadata in your applicaition.yml. A skeleton client app can be like below:

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloOauthServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloOauthServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource){
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
     clientId: client
     clientSecret: secret
     accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9090/oauth/token
     userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9090/oauth/authorize
     auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
     registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:9090/login
     clientAuthenticationScheme: form
     grant-type: passwordR
    resource:
     token-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/oauth/check_token
```

in this way you have guarantee that the OAuth2RestTemplate of spring will use and upgrade the token